# Swift-Xcode: why isn't my self.tableView.reloadData() call loading the promised data into my table / cells?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

HERE is the latest code.  I've tried moving the tableView.reloadData() all over the place - anyone have any ideas or suggestions?  I am still staring at an empty table that says "no results" when i make my API call and get exactly what I need in return.

I have also reset the constraints all over my storyboard - I feel like I am missing something very simple here

```
import UIKit
import Alamofire
import MapKit
//import CoreLocation

class ToolTableViewController: UITableViewController, CLLocationManagerDelegate {

//    @IBOutlet weak var tableview: UITableView!
    var jsonArray:NSMutableArray?
    var tools = [Tool]()

    @IBOutlet weak var toolListSearchBar: UISearchBar!

    let locationManager = CLLocationManager()
    var currentLat: CLLocationDegrees = 0.0
    var currentLong: CLLocationDegrees = 0.0



    func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
        let locValue:CLLocationCoordinate2D = manager.location!.coordinate
//        print("locations = \(locValue.latitude) \(locValue.longitude)")
        let location = locations.last! as CLLocation
        currentLat = location.coordinate.latitude
        currentLong = location.coordinate.longitude
    }


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()


        self.tableView.dataSource = self
        self.tableView.delegate = self

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { self.tableView.reloadData() })

        self.tableView.registerClass(ToolTableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "ToolTableViewCell")
        self.locationManager.delegate = self
        self.locationManager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()

        self.locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()

        if CLLocationManager.locationServicesEnabled() {
            locationManager.delegate = self
            locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyNearestTenMeters
            locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()



        }
        else{
            print("Location service disabled");
        }
//       self.tableView.reloadData()
        // Load the sample data.
    }

    func refresh(sender: AnyObject) {
        // Reload the data

        self.tableView.reloadData()
    }


    func searchBarSearchButtonClicked(searchbar: UISearchBar)
    {
        searchbar.resignFirstResponder()
        tools = []

        let defaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
        let userid: Int = defaults.objectForKey("toolBeltUserID") as! Int

        let searchTerm = String(toolListSearchBar.text!)
        print(searchTerm)



        Alamofire.request(.GET, "http://localhost:3000/tools/search", parameters: ["keyword": searchTerm, "latitude": currentLat, "longitude": currentLong,
            "user": userid]) .responseJSON {response in
            if let JSON = response.result.value {
                print("\(JSON)")

               for i in 0 ..< JSON.count {

                let owner = JSON[i].objectForKey("owner")
                let tool = JSON[i].objectForKey("tool")
                let title = tool!["title"] as! String!
                let ownerId = owner!["id"] as! Int!
                let distanceToTool = JSON[i].objectForKey("distance") as! Double
                var description: String

                    if let des = tool!["description"] as?  NSNull {
                        description = ""
                    } else {
                        description = (tool!["description"] as? String!)!
                    }

                    let myTool = Tool(title: title!, description: description, ownerId: ownerId!, distance: distanceToTool)

                    self.tools.append(myTool)

                }



            } else {
                print("Sent search term, but no response")
            }

             self.refresh(self)
        }

    }

    override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

        return tools.count
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cellIdentifier = "ToolTableViewCell"
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(cellIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) as! ToolTableViewCell
        let tool = tools[indexPath.row]

        cell.title?.text = tool.title
//       print(tool.title)
//        cell.toolListDescription?.text = tool.description
        cell.ownerId = tool.ownerId
//        print(tool.ownerId)
//       print(tool.distance)
//        cell.distance?.text = "\(tool.distance)mi"

        print(cell)
        return cell
        print(cell)
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

}
```

Comment: What happens if instead of doing this : `self.tools += [myTool]` you do this `self.tools.append(myTool)` ?

Comment: Thanks Randy - I got the same result with this small change.  It looks like my array of JSON objects is exactly what I want but my TableViewController doesn't seem to get the hint - looking into specifying the datasource for my TableViewController ..?

Comment: If you put a breakpoint in `tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:`method and you `po tools.count`, what do you see ?

Comment: Oh, and also, try to call `tableView.reloadData()` in the main thread :
`dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue, {
   self.tableView.reloadData
})`

Comment: Getting a print(tools.count) of 4 which is accurate - so the array is getting properly populated - it seems

Comment: So what is the problem actually, you cells are empty ?

Comment: `cellForRowAtIndexPath` gets called, right ? If so, then there might be an issue with your `ToolTableViewCell`, could you show the implementation of this class ?

Comment: Yep!  as silly as it sounds - my executed cells are not appending to the table

Comment: Btw, it doesn't really make sense to call `reloadData` before `registerClass` in your `viewDidLoad` method

Comment: import UIKit
class ToolTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

    
    
    IBOutlet var toolListTitle: UILabel!
    IBOutlet var distance: UILabel!
 
    IBOutlet var toolListDescription: UILabel!

    var ownerId = Int()
    
}

Comment: I am starting to suspect issue is with my ToolTableViewCell file connection to the TableViewController itself somehow

Comment: Are you sure your constraints are well defined ? Could you share your ib file for `ToolTableViewCell` ?

Comment: import UIKit
class ToolTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

    // MARK: Properties
    
    IBOutlet var toolListTitle: UILabel!
    IBOutlet var distance: UILabel!
 
    IBOutlet var toolListDescription: UILabel!

    var ownerId = Int()
    
}

Comment: Thanks Randy - I am not sure about my constraints :/

Comment: and the return is definitely hitting the cellForRowAtIndexPath - which makes me think the cells are not properly getting appended to the client - perhaps because of constraint issues..

Comment: I'm actually populating the cells and printing them out as such:

Comment: <ToolBelt_4_0.ToolTableViewCell: 0x7a8f2c00; baseClass = UITableViewCell; frame = (0 44; 320 103); autoresize = W; layer = <CALayer: 0x79f27ae0>>

Comment: The frame looks correct, so I'm pretty sure your constraints are wrong. Are you using a .xib file ? Could you upload it so we can take a look at it ?

Comment: I can send you my storyboard code if that helps

Comment: I've tried resetting the constraints to the labels in the ToolTableViewCell view a few different ways to no avail yet

Comment: Can you edit your question and post your storyboard file ?

Comment: Gladly - posted above - thank so much for you attention on this Randy

Comment: Your constraints don't seem to be properly set. It's kind of hard to check a storyboard though. I suggest two things :

1 - you check what happens with a normal `UITableViewCell` to see if you can display something ( use the `textLabel` attribute )

2 - you rebuild the whole UI related to your cell

Comment: all constraints have been reset on my storyboard in every view - this is really frustrating

Comment: Did you try using an actual `UITableViewCell` ?

Comment: Yes since yesterday

Comment: Fiddlesticks, I've been hitting the 'return cell' for 24 hours now without my table being appended with the cells

Answer (score 0):

The call to reloadData belongs inside the completion closure for the Alamofire request.

Where have it now it's getting called before the Alamofire request call is complete.

I don't remember if Alamofire's completion closures are run on the main thread or on a background thread. If they're run on a background thread then you'll need to wrap the call to reloadData in a `dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue){ }` call.

### EDIT:

I said the call to reloadData belongs inside the closure for the Alamofire request call. Like this:

```
    Alamofire.request(.GET, "http://localhost:3000/tools/search", parameters: ["keyword": searchTerm, "latitude": currentLat, "longitude": currentLong,
        "user": userid]) .responseJSON {response in
        if let JSON = response.result.value {
            print("\(JSON)")

           for i in 0 ..< JSON.count {

            let owner = JSON[i].objectForKey("owner")
            let tool = JSON[i].objectForKey("tool")
            let title = tool!["title"] as! String!
            let ownerId = owner!["id"] as! Int!
            let distanceToTool = JSON[i].objectForKey("distance") as! Double
            var description: String

                if let des = tool!["description"] as?  NSNull {
                    description = ""
                } else {
                    description = (tool!["description"] as? String!)!
                }

                let myTool = Tool(title: title!, description: description, ownerId: ownerId!, distance: distanceToTool)

                self.tools.append(myTool)

            }

          //This call is inside the closure for the request call.
          dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) 
          { 
            //Call reloadData from the main thread
            self.tableView.reloadData() 
            //Or you could call your refresh method.
          }
        } else {
            print("Sent search term, but no response")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Duncan - I am trying a few things with this function

Comment: Duncan is correct. You must do the reload data call on the main thread

Comment: @Feldur, do you know if Alamofire calls it's request completion block on the main thread or on a worker thread? It's been a while since I've used it.

Comment: i have had zero luck with this dispatch_async call in the main thread

Comment: Edit your question to show your new code. You don't want to call dispatch_async in the main thread, you want to add a call to dispatch_async in your closure, which causes the code inside the dispatch_async to be called on the main thread.

Comment: Thanks Duncan - i just put my new code up there - take a look - any thoughts?

Comment: Also, there's no point to calling reloadData from viewDidLoad. Get rid of that.

Comment: oddly I didn't have this problem at all last time I made a tableview catch a call

Comment: dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
                    
                    self.refresh(self)
                    
                })

Comment: func refresh(sender: AnyObject) {
        // Reload the data
        
        self.tableView.reloadData()
    }

Comment: Thanks Duncan - let me take a close look at your solution - much appreciated

Comment: Yes i've tried this a few different ways.  At this point i'm certain there is a problem with the connection between my cell and my table.  I appreciate your help Duncan!

Comment: So set a breakpoint in your refresh method (get rid of the call to it in viewDidLoad.) When it's called, examine your tools array. Also set a breakpoint in cellForRowAtIndexPath and again check the tools array.

Comment: ▿ 4 elements
  ▿ [0] : <Tool: 0x7a83adf0>
  ▿ [1] : <Tool: 0x7a80ce30>
  ▿ [2] : <Tool: 0x7a81bbc0>
  ▿ [3] : <Tool: 0x7a8213d0>

Comment: The cells are actually getting populated! Have I not properly specified the datatype?  Unreal this has held me up for a day now